# Pandas Plotting Display all date values on x-axis (matplolib only displays few values) formatted as MMM-YYYY

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel(DATA_DIR+"/"+file_list[0], index_col="Date")
df.head(5)
```

[image]

```
smooth = df['Pur. Rate'].rolling(window=20).mean()
smooth.plot()
```

[image]

I get the following graph and need to plot all the date values for every MONTH-YEAR on the x-axis.
I want to display all the months and years formatted diagonally on the x-axis in the format (Feb-19). I can make the size of the plot larger to fit all as I will save it as jpg.

I want the x-axis to have the following values:
Jan 16, Feb 16, Mar 16, Apr 16, May 16, Jun 16, Jul 16, Aug 16, Sep 16, Oct 16, Nov 16, Dec 16, Jan 17, Feb 17 …
(I want to display all these values, matplotlib automatically truncates this, I want to avoid that)

Comment: You have to set the correct Locator and Formatter in matplotlib to get the desired xticks. Please read the [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/dates_api.html) and ask, if you still don't manage. In general, custom labeling involves two steps: [locating the ticks and formatting their labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=locators). If you want to work with this more often, you should get familiar with these concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to set both, the Locator and the Formatter. This is explained well in the matplotlib documentation for [graphs in general](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) and [separately for datetime axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html). See also an explanation of the [TickLocators](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html). The formatting codes are derived from Python's [strftime() and strptime() format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter


#fake data
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"Dates": pd.date_range("20180101", periods=n, freq="10d"), "A": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=n), "B": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=n),})
df.set_index("Dates", inplace=True)
print(df)

ax = df.plot()

#defines the tick location 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
#defines the label format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b-%y"))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelrotation= 90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use matplotlib and not pandas plot, and do something like this to plot the dates in the format you specified:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y') # date formatter for matplotlib
                                      # %b is Month abbreviated name, %Y is the Year

# ... after some code

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# Plot data ...

ax.set_xticks("""... define how often to show the date""")
```

You can get the data out of the data frame with something like: `.to_numpy()` or `.values()`.

Refer to this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) for the `set_xticks` function.

Comment: This does not seem to work it just shows Jan-01 for all years. I get the implementation you did for formatting, it is quite nice. But it still does not show all values in the x-axis

Comment: Sorry I misread your request. I updated the answer. I way formatting the "day", not the "year".

Comment: Thanks but that was not my question I figured you accidentally had done day instead of year. The main issue I face is displaying all the dates on the x-axis. I have updated the question to make this more clear. Sorry if it was a little ambiguous.

Comment: I also added the set_xticks function. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

With just pandas functions, you can use *stftime()* to replace your dates schema index '%Y-%m-%d' by a new form '%b-%Y' and some params in *plot*.

```
smoothdf.plot(xticks=smoothdf.index.strftime('%m-%Y').unique()).set_xticklabels(smoothdf.index.strftime('%b-%Y').unique())
```

*xticks* to specify wich label you absolutly want to see.

*set_xticklabels* to modify the list of labels.

Comment: I do not have that big an issue with formatting. The main issue I am facing is to show all the month values on the x-axis. Pyplot automatically just displays a few values on the x-axis

Comment: Okay, I make an entire correction, I think it's working now.