# Spacing out dates on the X-Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I'm analyzing coronavirus data in my country and I want to plot the data on new deaths, and total deaths in one plot. Initially I plotted it using the inbuilt `plot` function on the dataframe.

```
reports.plot(x='date', y='new_deaths')
reports.plot(x='date', y='total_deaths')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('cases')
plt.show()
```

Which yielded these images.
[image]

[image]

However, I wanted to change the legends, and have them to be in one plot instead so I went ahead and used `plt.subplot(111)`.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.plot(ph_reports_april.date, ph_reports_april.new_deaths, label='New Deaths')
ax.plot(ph_reports_april.date, ph_reports_april.total_deaths, label='Total Deaths')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Cases')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

It got the job done except for one little problem.
[image]

The dates are congested. Is there a way to have the date similar to how the `dataframe.plot()` function works? I've browse through this site and haven't found anything of value regarding on spacing out the values of date in the x-axis.

Comment: what happens when you pass the `ax` to the dataframe plotting function `reports.plot(x='date', y='new_deaths', ax=ax)` and `reports.plot(x='date', y='total_deaths', ax=ax)`?

Comment: Set in matplotlib the Locator according to your needs. There are many examples on SO, lazily, [I will link to one of my own answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343940/8881141).