# Python : yfinance axis formatting issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, finance

Yo ! First of all thanks for your help.
I know there are some similar topics but I want to understand and get an explaination please.
Trying to plot stock prices evolution , I used this code:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "AMZN"]
start_date = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)
end_date = dt.datetime(2021,2,10)
prices = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers,
    start = start_date,
    end = end_date)
prices["Adj Close"].plot()
plt.show()
```

I don't understand why when I plot the year part (x axis) gives something like 3990-01-05 ,etc.

Thanks for your help.

JaNa

Comment: Thanks for the copy-pastable code sample. I tried running it and [it looks fine to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKERZ.png), no problem with the dates. I am using matplotlib 3.3.2. Maybe the [epoch](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.set_epoch) has been changed somehow, you can check it with `plt.rcParams['date.epoch']`.

Comment: It seems you want to change the x-tick label format using `DateFormatter` (many examples on SO, [see for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343940/8881141) although it is not mad clear into what format you want to change it.

Comment: Mr.T I want to get something like YYYY MM DD . Using the command plt.rcParams I got 1970-01-01T00:00:00 + a message "The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  base = dates.epoch2num(dt.asi8 / 1.0e9)". How  can I fix it please ? thanks