# Full datetimes in x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, plot

I am new to programming in general, and I have started with Python. I have a project where i have to create various plots (y-axis: voltage, frequency etc,  x-axis: exact datetimes ) from a csv file which contains the meterings of a home smart meter. I try to create a plot between 2 certain datetimes (not from start to end). I have fairly managed to do it but I face some problems in concern of the x-axis. I want to get for example "2020-09-22 09:00:02" but I get for example "9-22 10".

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oEFG.png)

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/data/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8881141). Post the formatted text directly here on SO. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71855921/edit).

Comment: As for your question, see for instance here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343940/8881141