# how to create line graph with datetime variable, using only its time component?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time

I have a table like this:

[image]

and I would like to display dep_delay per time of day. Basically, I want to get rid of the date in dep_sched_time, group by the time and plot the dep_delay per time.

As simple as it sounds, I am stuck for quite some time here. Extracting the time only by using .dt.time does not help as matplotlib throws the error

`float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'datetime.time'`

I also did not manage to convert the time to float or something similar.
What is the best way to solve this?

Thank you already!

Comment: [Format the displayed date](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#date-formatters) instead of trying to convert the input. An example is, for instance, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65343940/8881141